# Parsing a DOCX file with nested tables and extracting nested tables as they appear

Tags: python, parsing, docx, pdfplumber

I'm working on a project where I need to extract information from DOCX files that contain nested tables. My goal is to parse these files and retrieve the nested tables in their original structure. I've tried various approaches, including using libraries like python-docx and docx2txt, but I'm facing challenges when it comes to nested tables.

Is there a way to parse a DOCX file with nested tables and fetch the nested tables exactly as they appear in the document?

Ideally, I'd like to maintain the nested table's structure, including rows, columns, and cell content.
I have tried multiple solution like (Convert docx to pdf and use pdf-plumber, or capture the cell image) but I couldn't find a straightforward solution for handling nested tables.
If you have experience or insights into how to approach this problem, I'd greatly appreciate your guidance or code snippets that could help me achieve this.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.